# automate org-mode html export via elisp

Tags: automation, elisp, org-mode

I wanted to automate the html export of two org-mode files using a elisp defun defined in `~/.emacs`. I wrote the following code:

```
(defun publish-custom-orgs ()
  "publish certain org files as html files"
  (interactive)
  (find-file "~/org/a.org")
  (org-export-as-html)
  (find-file "~/org/b.org")
  (org-export-as-html)
)
```

But this does not export the files; instead, it shows a strange output in the minibuffer:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try org-export-as-html-batch

```
(defun publish-custom-orgs ()
  "publish certain org files as html files"
  (interactive)
  (find-file "~/org/a.org")
  (org-export-as-html-batch)
  (find-file "~/org/b.org")
  (org-export-as-html-batch)
)
```

Comment: org-export-as-html expects at least one argument. `(org-export-as-html org-export-headline-levels)` or `(org-export-as-html 3)`must be OK. [code line in git](http://orgmode.org/w/?p=org-mode.git;a=blob;f=lisp/org-html.el;h=a2cf2c763edc4d8ac83ad7e84128ec4a67d24b17;hb=HEAD#l1099)